# How to execute save in a Laravel Listener

Tags: laravel

I try to import a file with Laravel Command. The import works well. After the import, Laravel triggers an event. This works also well.

With a listener, I catch the event. It works well when I do as example `dd('it works')`!

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\EventsNew\Notifiables\ConsignmentCreatedViaApi;

class ConsignmentCreatedListener
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function handle($event)
    {
        dd('it works');
    }
}
```

But if I try to save some values into the db, it doesn't work, neighter it returns an error:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Models\Settlement;

class ConsignmentCreatedListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle( $event)
    {
        Settlement::create([
            'consignment_id'=> 1
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried to execute `Settlement::create` in the console command and it works.

Isn't it possible to insert something into the db after an avent? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Is insert work in other places example, in the controller?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I did an error in the import. after the first import, there was no event fired.

Comment: Your code should work without any errors. I don't see any errors in that

Comment: What are `some values`? You need to make sure you have those values in the event to be able to insert them in DB in the event

Comment: Try `insert` instead of `create`